# SWR stuck in loading state. Even after request is completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, api-design, swr

I am using SWR to complete a simple API request however after I just finished formatting the API how I wanted SWR is now stuck In it's loading state and I am very confused as to why I have tried a few different things and none have yet to resolve my issue.

I know the response from the API includes a JSON object and in the code I did try to convert to a JavaScript object however it seems to not help.

In the `fetcher` I have set it to return the data and dig into the JSON object, If I remove `British_Roles` from the `return` then Next.js will return an error saying the map is not a function.

Have a feeling it could be a simple issue I am missing, but please keep in mind I am no pro. Any help would be greatly accepted

```react
import {
  Table,
  TableCaption,
  Thead,
  Tr,
  Th,
  Tbody,
  Td,
  Tfoot,
  Text,
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionButton,
  AccordionPanel,
  AccordionIcon,
  Box,
  Center,
  Stack,
  Heading,
  VStack,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";

const fetcher = async (url, key) => {
  const res = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${key}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  return res.data.data.attributes;
};

export const InsurgentDropdown = () => {
  var key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
  var key =
    "xxx";
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    ["https://api.squadkitresearch.net/api/britishes/1?populate=%2A", key],
    fetcher
  );

  if (error)
    return console.log(error), (<div>Failed to load {error.message}</div>);
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

// using roles or data in the map below makes no difference
  return (
    <>
        {data.map((faction) => (
          <VStack p="5">
            <Accordion allowToggle>
              <AccordionItem>
                <AccordionButton>
                  <Box flex="1" textAlign="left">
                    <Heading fontSize="20px">
                      {faction.role_name || "Data Error"}
                    </Heading>
                  </Box>
                  <AccordionIcon />
                </AccordionButton>
                <AccordionPanel>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </AccordionPanel>
              </AccordionItem>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion allowToggle>
              <AccordionItem>
                <h2>
                  <AccordionButton>
                    <Box flex="1" textAlign="left">
                      <Heading fontSize="20px">
                        {faction.role_name || "Data Error"}
                      </Heading>
                    </Box>
                    <AccordionIcon />
                  </AccordionButton>
                </h2>
                <AccordionPanel pb={4}>
                  <Table variant="striped" colorScheme="teal">
                    <TableCaption fontSize="15px">
                      {faction.role_name || "Squad Kit Weapon Name"} Role
                      Information
                    </TableCaption>
                    <Thead>
                      <Tr>
                        <Th fontSize="20px">Primary Weapon</Th>
                        <Th fontSize="20px">Magazine Size</Th>
                        <Th fontSize="20px">Weapon Sights Type</Th>
                        <Th fontSize="20px">Weapon Firing Modes</Th>
                        <Th isNumeric fontSize="20px">
                          Magazine Count
                        </Th>
                      </Tr>
                    </Thead>
                    <Tbody>
                      <Tr>
                        <Td>{faction.Primary || "Data Error"}</Td>
                        <Td>
                          {faction.Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount ||
                            "Data Error"}
                        </Td>
                        <Td>{faction.Primary_Sights || "Data Error"}</Td>
                        <Td>{faction.Primary_Firing_Modes || "Data Error"}</Td>
                        <Td>
                          {faction.Primary_Magazine_Amount || "Data Error"}
                        </Td>
                      </Tr>
                    </Tbody>
                    <Tr>
                      <Th fontSize="20px">Secondary Weapon</Th>
                      <Th fontSize="20px">Magazine Size</Th>
                      <Th fontSize="20px">Weapon Sights Type</Th>
                      <Th fontSize="20px">Weapon Firing Modes</Th>
                      <Th isNumeric fontSize="20px">
                        Magazine Count
                      </Th>
                    </Tr>
                  </Table>
                </AccordionPanel>
              </AccordionItem>
            </Accordion>
          </VStack>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

// API Response

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "Role_Name": "British Squad Lead (Iron Sights)",
            "createdAt": "2022-02-05T05:55:35.926Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-02-05T05:55:38.194Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-02-05T05:55:38.184Z",
            "locale": "en",
            "British_Roles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "role_name": "British Squad Lead (Iron Sights)",
                    "Primary": "L85A2 + Foregrip + Bipod",
                    "Primary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                    "Primary_Firing_Modes": "Auto/Single",
                    "Primary_Magazine_Amount": 7,
                    "Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount": 30,
                    "Secondary": "L131A1",
                    "Secondary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                    "Secondary_Firing_Modes": "Single",
                    "Secondary_Magazine_Amount": 2,
                    "Secondary_Magazine_Round_Amount": null,
                    "Secondary_Knife": "SA80 Bayonet"
                }
            ],
            "British_Role_Extras": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.third-slot",
                    "Third_Slot_Item": "L109A1 Fragmentation Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.forth-slot",
                    "Forth_Slot_Item": "L132A1 White Smoke Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "__component": "loadouts.forth-slot",
                    "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Orange Smoke Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "__component": "loadouts.forth-slot",
                    "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Yellow Smoke Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.fifth-slot",
                    "Fith_Slot_Item": "Field Dressing",
                    "Item_Amount": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.sixth-slot",
                    "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Field Binoculars",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "__component": "loadouts.sixth-slot",
                    "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Rally Point",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                }
            ],
            "localizations": {
                "data": []
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the fetcher return a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `attributes` in object. Try changing

```
return res.data.British_Roles;
```

to

```
return res.data.attributes.British_Roles;
```

In future, always try to debug by adding a console.log before the return value, to ensure you are returning the correct values.

```
const fetcher = async (url, key) => {
  const res = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${key}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  //so you know the error occurs here due to missing 'attributes'
  console.log(res.data.attributes.British_Roles)
  return res.data.attributes.British_Roles;
};
```

```js
const response = {
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "Role_Name": "British Squad Lead (Iron Sights)",
            "createdAt": "2022-02-05T05:55:35.926Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-02-05T05:55:38.194Z",
            "publishedAt": "2022-02-05T05:55:38.184Z",
            "locale": "en",
            "British_Roles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "role_name": "British Squad Lead (Iron Sights)",
                    "Primary": "L85A2 + Foregrip + Bipod",
                    "Primary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                    "Primary_Firing_Modes": "Auto/Single",
                    "Primary_Magazine_Amount": 7,
                    "Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount": 30,
                    "Secondary": "L131A1",
                    "Secondary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                    "Secondary_Firing_Modes": "Single",
                    "Secondary_Magazine_Amount": 2,
                    "Secondary_Magazine_Round_Amount": null,
                    "Secondary_Knife": "SA80 Bayonet"
                }
            ],
            "British_Role_Extras": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.third-slot",
                    "Third_Slot_Item": "L109A1 Fragmentation Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.forth-slot",
                    "Forth_Slot_Item": "L132A1 White Smoke Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "__component": "loadouts.forth-slot",
                    "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Orange Smoke Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "__component": "loadouts.forth-slot",
                    "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Yellow Smoke Grenade",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.fifth-slot",
                    "Fith_Slot_Item": "Field Dressing",
                    "Item_Amount": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "__component": "loadouts.sixth-slot",
                    "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Field Binoculars",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "__component": "loadouts.sixth-slot",
                    "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Rally Point",
                    "Item_Amount": 1
                }
            ],
            "localizations": {
                "data": []
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {}
}

console.log(response.data.attributes.British_Roles)
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that thanks and thanks for the console log tip I will remember that one! That has fixed the loading issue, but now it's saying that `British_Roles` is undefined?

Comment: which line showing the error? Unless your axios is not returning the right response, else base on the object you showed, I've demonstrated that the `response.data.attributes.British_roles` works.

Comment: `var roles = JSON.parse(data)` can be omitted by the way.

Comment: I removed the `var roles = JSON.parse(data)` But the issue is coming from the `  return res.data.attributes.British_Roles;` line on the fetcher

Comment: do a console.log on `res` and see if there's error

Comment: Okay did that https://imgur.com/a/wRehTfU thats what the console spits out I cannot open the data tab any further

Comment: well then u got to open up `data` and see fht object structure..

Comment: If I make the console log `res.data` I can clearly see all the response including the `British_Roles` but it is an array, could this possibly cause an undefined error? To add to this if I add `attributes` to the console log it then does return an undefined for a weird reason

Comment: You have to screenshot that since I don't know what you get from response.

Comment: Okay, I've eddited the original code to show the changes I have made, half of the issue was I wasn't digging in enough into the `res` instead of `res.data` it should have been `res.data.data` Once I made the return `res.data.data.attributes` I am now getting an error stating that the map function is not a function `TypeError: data.map is not a function` console https://imgur.com/a/jqwBdk4

Comment: Please be consistent with your requirement. `data.data.attributes.British_roles` is an array and you can use data.map. `data.data.attributes` is an object and you cannot use map. If you want to return `data.data.attributes` then you need to use `data.British_Roles.map`. IF you want to use `data.map` then you need to return `res.data.data.attributes.British_Roles`, you get the idea?

Comment: Everything is working I appreciate the help. And sorry for the mismatch I tend to confuse myself at times haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241749/discussion-between-matdoak-and-someone-special).